# How to understand the meaning of 愛{いと}しさ

Tags: grammar, meaning

I know that from adjective we can make adjectival noun like: 高{たか}い -> 高さ - means *high* and *hight*. But how to understand/translate the word 愛しさ? I heard it in one of *C-ute* songs.

Comment: Have you looked up さ?  What did you find?

Comment: I can find one relative English translation - `darlingness` - but it is not present in my English dictionary. So it is hard to understand even in English, and after that - my native language is Lithuanian..

Comment: Since I can't find さ in the J-E dictionaries provides by yahoo and goo, here's the entry from the GG: -さ (-sa)〔接尾辞〕 (性質) -ness; (その程度) (the) degree [amount, extent] of…. EXAMPLES: 静かさ　quietness; quiet [⇒静かさ] , 自然さ　naturalness, セクシーさ　sexiness, 眠さ　sleepiness, 重さ　weight [⇒おもさ], 困難さ　the degree of difficulty, スポーティーなデザインで商品の新しさを表現する　express the product's newness [novelty] through its sporty design, あまりのとんでもなさに読むのをやめた.　It was so ridiculous I quit reading it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've figured out what you are asking about.
Mental adjective + さ can refer to ***one's feeling*** as well as *quality* invokes the emotion.
I'm not sure I'm able to tell their difference using English words, but you can paraphrase it with 〜と思う気持ち when it means the feeling.
Maybe what you encountered was this kind of usage, where in this case 愛しさ = 愛しいと思う気持ち → あなたが愛しいと思う気持ち ≈ "earnest love for you".